# Tkinter Label class not appearing when used within a class

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I am creating a basic GUI with multiple, but similar, label structures. However, when I created a class to help minimize the text, and placed it within a label frame, the label frame does not appear. This only happens when I use the class within a class, and if I use the regular label and label frame classes everything works out well. I'm trying to figure out as to why this is the case.

My code:

main.py

```
from tkinter import *

def main():
    main_window = Tk()
    app = First(main_window)
    main_window.mainloop()

class GPULabel(Label):
    def __init__(self, master, varText):
    varText = varText
    super().__init__()
    self["text"] = varText
    self["anchor"] = "w"
    self["width"] = 25

class First:
    def __init__(self, root):
        self.root = root
        self.root.title('First Window')

        self.myFrame = LabelFrame(self.root, text="frame")
        self.myFrame.pack()

        label1 = GPULabel(self.myFrame, "label")
        lable1.pack()

if __name__ == '__main__'
    main()
```

This opens a window but it is completely empty. However, if I swap to a regular `Label(self.myFrame...)` then the window pops up correctly. Why is that? And is there a way to make my original method work?

Comment: Your class isn't passing on the `master` parameter to the superclass `__init__()`, which causes the widget to default to being a child of the root window.  And with no children, your LabelFrame collapses to nothing.

Comment: The indentation is your code example is broken (the code under `def __init__(self, master, varText):`)

Comment: @jasonharper I sorta understand. You're saying since my class isn't passing the ```master``` then my label doesn't share the same space as the class itself, and just kinda disappears. I'm not fully sure how to pass it down. I tried adding ```master``` to my superclass, but it resulted in an error saying the object has no attribute 'tk'

Comment: Nevermind, I got it :) For anyone in the future, I had to change the super into ```super().__init__(master)```